# Cannot Get Uniform Styling Across Browsers For Calendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a page with a calendar on it which uses Jquery to get data from the server and populates.

For some reason, it works perfectly on chrome, but on firefox it falls apart and canon seem to style it to get it to look the same as in chrome.

[Here is the link](http://www.mycityvenue.com/Apartment58). Please open in chrome and then in firefox or any ie to see what I mean.

Comment: Would it be possible to put the relevant bits in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

The file profile.css has style `display: block` for anything with class `special-event`, so the table cells with that class no longer behave like table cells.

My guess is that you meant to write `.special event a` or something; that would be more in line with the other selectors in that rule.

I couldn't say, however, why Chrome treats this rule differently.

Comment: You're welcome. Hey, could you mark this answer by clicking on the tick mark? Then future visitors will know this question has been resolved.